# how to match a string constructed by given sub strings by regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, substring, match

what should I do to match a string constructed by substrings "CC" "LC" "SW" "RP" "WP" "DT" "LO" "CR" "RC" by regular expression in c#.for example:
the input string is **"D:(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU) (A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)"**and how to match the substring **(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)** in it.

thanks,regards

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify anything about the text surrounding the 2 character substrings (the As and the semicolons), so to be flexible, here's a regex that pulls out all strings that are surrounded by brackets, start with anything, end with anything, and contains one or more of the substrings you specified:

```
var resultList = new List<string>();
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\(.*?(CC|LC|SW|RP|WP|DT|LO|CR|RC)+.*?\))", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) 
{
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

When run on your example above, the following are extracted:

```
(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;AU)
(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)
(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)
(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)
```

Comment: Thanks.It works fine,but this pulls out strings like (A;;CCCCLCRPRC;;;AU) too (the CC appear twice).

Comment: So each of the substrings can only appear a maximum of once?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match exact string, you can simply use `String.IndexOf` method.

Answer (score 1):

or You may use String.Contains method to find whether a string is part of main string or not